# Is there any way to use trunc function in the option() command in R?

Tags: r

I am getting an output through a program in R as 20.0000000 16.0000000  7.4650426  0.9996772.
Here I want to get all the output values in fix 4 places (I don't need to round these figures up to 4th digits). So, I want to use trunc() with option command in beginning. But how???

Answer (score 2):

With `options` it is possible to set the number of digits, but it uses `round` and not `trunc`. The `?options` helpfile says:

"digits: controls the number of significant (see signif) digits to print when printing numeric values. It is a suggestion only. Valid values are 1...22 with default 7. See the note in print.default about values greater than 15."

here an example:

```
> options(digits=16)
> 1/3
[1] 0.3333333333333333
> options(digits=2)
> 1/3
[1] 0.33
>
```

This should work in most cases, but some packages may overwrite these settings.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `sprintf`

```
 sprintf('%.4f', v1)
```